# Display CTP Files as PHP Files in PHPStorm

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm

I have a project running on CakePHP.  All of my views are stored as ctp files.  How do I render my ctp files so I have the same visual formatting that's present when I look at a file that is stored as a PHP file?  In Notepad++, I was able to do this by selecting from the 'Language' toolbar option.  Is there a similar feature in PHPStorm?

Comment: Just a note: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16723

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` | **File Types**, assign this extension to the `PHP Files`.

Comment: any idea if this .ctp could be added in the default configuration for PhpStorm 6? Seems to be an easy thing to implement and would at least partially complete this issue; http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-760 :)

Comment: I couldn't find an issue for this specifically, so I created one; http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16723

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | File Types in PHPStorm 9.

Comment: On Mac: PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor > File Types > PHP ... kinda dumb that you have to put an asterisk and period in front of every file extension in the list (like when would it ever NOT have those)

Comment: PHPStorm 2017.1 on MAC: Preferences - Editor - File and Code Templates - Files

Answer (score 20):

> In PHP Storm 2017: File | Settings | Editor | File Types

Add **.ctp** into PHP's **Registered Patterns** tab

```
Select PHP & In tab Registered Patterns > Click + > add .cpt
```

[image]

Comment: how to add .ctp into PHP'S registered patterns ? can you please help me?

Comment: Hi there, in tab Registered Patterns > Click + > add .cpt