# PhpStorm: write in PHP, HTML and JS in ctp file

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp, phpstorm

Using CakePHP to write code, usually *.ctp files contains PHP, HTML and JavaScript code. Unfortunately PhpStorm recognize PHP and HTML only:

[image: PhpStorm example]

Of course if I edit a JavaScript-only file (.js) the highlight and autocompletion work.

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877005/display-ctp-files-as-php-files-in-phpstorm) answer, but I cannot assign the same extension to multiple languages.

How to edit all the three languages in PhpStorm?

Comment: PhpStorm can recognize JavaScript just fine .. it's just that you use custom code to denote `<script>` tag (where you store your JS code in this file). If you use `<script>` tag instead it will work just fine. I do not think that anything can be done here, unless it's supported by Cake-specific plugin (that knows what `$this->Html->scriptStart(...` does and may inject JS language into that place).

Comment: @LazyOne, that's true. But a lot of times other users told me to use native function of `CakePHP` instead of writing stuff directly. Now I have to do the opposite... I'm learning PHP/CakePHP and it's confusing!

Comment: PhpStorm itself cannot inject custom language between 2 PHP function calls (that tells "start script tag here" and "end script tag here"). It supports specific tags, HEREDOC labels, some other tags in other template languages (e.g. Smarty or twig) as anchor points for injection (where to start and stop) .. but plain PHP function calls ... nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
<?php $this->append('script');?>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});

</script>
<?php $this->end();?>
```